# Download json file from MongoDB atlas with python

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I want to download the entire collection and put it into a json file. I've tried (see below) but it doesnt work.

```
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pymongo
from pathlib import Path

myclient = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://<DbName>:<DbPass>@<DbName>.a3b2ai.mongodb.net/<DbName>?retryWrites=true&w=majority")

db = myclient["PlayerPrices"]

Collection = db["Playstation"]

payload = db.inventory.find( {} ) #I think this command is the problem
with open(str(Path(__file__).parents[1]) + '\Main\playstation_1.json', 'r+') as file:
                json.dump(payload, file, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you need to convert the Pymongo Cursor to support json format.

```
# Python Program for 
# demonstrating the  
# PyMongo Cursor to JSON 


# Importing required modules 
from pymongo import MongoClient 
from bson.json_util import dumps, loads 


# Connecting to MongoDB server 
# client = MongoClient('host_name', 
# 'port_number') 
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017) 

# Connecting to the database named 
# GFG 
mydatabase = client.GFG 

# Accessing the collection named 
# gfg_collection 
mycollection = mydatabase.College 

# Now creating a Cursor instance 
# using find() function 
cursor = mycollection.find() 

# Converting cursor to the list  
# of dictionaries 
list_cur = list(cursor) 

# Converting to the JSON 
json_data = dumps(list_cur, indent = 2)  

# Writing data to file data.json 
with open('data.json', 'w') as file: 
  file.write(json_data)
```

Resource taken from: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-pymongo-cursor-to-json/